# How to disable "refreshing effect" for specific button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created the button which can change `height`. Default `height` of button is `150px`. When you click on it, height changes to `300px`. Everytime when I refresh my page, `height` of button also "refreshes" (from `300px` to `default`). Which is normal, but I want to **disable** that effect for this specific button. How to do it?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: You're page isn't going to remember what height the button was set to unless you tell it to remember. Do you know how to store data on the client browser for your website?

Comment: Does the button do anything else besides change the height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use something like local storage to store the current state(the current state is the current height of your button in this case) of the button before the page is refreshed. Then whenever your page reloads, Get the previous state from your local storage and apply it to your button. There's other, more complicated methods depending on your framework/language etc, but first check out local storage.

Here's a link to learn more.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp